# Attach files uploaded with the contact form to mail

Tags: emails, 8

By default uploaded files in a contact form are uploaded to the server and a link is placed in the mail send to the recipients.

Is there a way to attach the uploaded files to the mail itself rather than/in addition to uploading them to the server?